# How can I install libatk-bridge2.0-0 so I can install Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I need to install Google Chrome.  When I do the Ubuntu Software Center says:

```
`cannot install 'libatk-bridge2.0-0'`
```

When I try to install it, this is what I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 debconf : Breaks: update-notifier-common (< 3.187~) but 0.119ubuntu8.7 is to be installed
 libdevmapper1.02.1 : Depends: dmsetup (>= 2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.4)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What do I need to do to get Chrome installed?

Comment: Is it required to use such an old version of Ubuntu? Can you use 20.04 instead?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, resolved by searching the `apt-cache search libatk`:

```bash
ubuntu@lucca:~$ sudo apt-cache search libatk
libatk-adaptor - AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge
libatk-bridge2.0-0 - AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge - shared library
libatk-bridge2.0-dev - Development files for the AT-SPI 2 toolkit bridge
libatk-wrapper-java - ATK implementation for Java using JNI
libatk-wrapper-java-jni - ATK implementation for Java using JNI (JNI bindings)
libatk1.0-0 - ATK accessibility toolkit
libatk1.0-data - Common files for the ATK accessibility toolkit
libatk1.0-dev - Development files for the ATK accessibility toolkit
libatk1.0-doc - Documentation files for the ATK toolkit
libatkmm-1.6-1v5 - C++ wrappers for ATK accessibility toolkit (shared libraries)
libatkmm-1.6-dev - C++ wrappers for ATK accessibility toolkit (development files)
libatkmm-1.6-doc - C++ wrappers for ATK accessibility toolkit (documentation)
libatk3.0-cil - CLI binding for the ATK accessibility toolkit
librust-atk-sys-dev - FFI bindings to libatk-1 - Rust source code
```